# how can I show the value of a column with a datatype datetime into a May 1, 2014 format?

Tags: c#, mysql

I have a datagridview that shows a table. When I click a value in the datagridview/table, it will be shown in a label.In the table, the date format is `10/18/2015`.I have the working code but I want the date format to be shown in a label will be like `May 1, 2014` instead of `10/18/2015 12:00:00 AM`

The datatype of the column `date` and `return_date` is `datetime`.

This is my working code:

```
 private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    if (e.RowIndex >= 0)    
        {
            DataGridViewRow row = this.dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex];

            lblfname.Text = row.Cells["First_Name"].Value.ToString();
            lbllname.Text = row.Cells["Last_Name"].Value.ToString();
            lblbook.Text = row.Cells["Title"].Value.ToString();
            lbldate.Text = row.Cells["Return_Date"].Value.ToString();
            lblbor.Text = row.Cells["Date"].Value.ToString();
     else
            {
                //do something
            }
        }
```

Edit: Here is my code for filtering my datagridview with the table

```
DataTable dt;
    public void refreshdata()
    {
        string loadstring = @"server=localhost;database=librarys;userid=root;password=1234;";
        MySqlConnection conDataBase = new MySqlConnection(loadstring);
        MySqlCommand cmdDataBase = new MySqlCommand("CALL `proc_returnborrowed`();", conDataBase);

        try
        {
            MySqlDataAdapter sda = new MySqlDataAdapter();
            sda.SelectCommand = cmdDataBase;
            dt = new DataTable();
            sda.Fill(dt);
            BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();

            bs.DataSource = dt;
            dataGridView1.DataSource = bs;
            sda.Update(dt);

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Comment: You can format it however you like; https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to convert your date into a [custom date format.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx)

```
lblbor.Text = row.Cells["Date"].Value.ToString("MMMM dd, yyyy", 
                  CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US"))
```

or simply

```
lblbor.Text = row.Cells["Date"].Value.ToString("MMMM dd, yyyy")
```

**EDIT:**

```
lblbor.Text = DateTime.ParseExact(row.Cells["Date"].Value, "MMMM dd, yyyy",
                                   CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: i already custom the date format  but i just get a very long and non-stop error.

i tried to input this `lblbor.Text = row.Cells["Date"].Value.ToString("MMMM dd, yyyy")`
it shows an error too

Comment: I cant tell but here is the  [screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/sTX9MWT.png).
This error appear when i use the `date_format` to view the table in the datagridview.

the code i use `SELECT Title,Author,First_Name,Last_Name,`date`,DATE_FORMAT(Return_Date, '%M %e, %Y') FROM borrowed WHERE STATUS = 1;`

Comment: @kielou:- Can you simply select your date like `SELECT Title,Author,First_Name,Last_Name,date,Return_Date FROM borrowed WHERE STATUS = 1;`

Comment: I am using that code right now and it works fine, but the problem is, i want the date format to be shown in a label `October 9, 2015` instead of `0/18/2015 12:00:00 AM`
Here is my [screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/uzpQMIE.png) for the working code.

Comment: @kielou:- What is the datatype of the column in your table?

Comment: both of the date and return_date are datetime

Comment: @kielou:- try this query in `SELECT Title,Author,First_Name,Last_Name,date,DATE_FORMAT(Return_Date,'%M %d %Y') FROM borrowed WHERE STATUS = 1;` and in your code simply `lblbor.Text = row.Cells["Date"].Value.ToString();`

Comment: I get the error when I filter the datagridview with the table.
I edited the post to show you the code